# CAN-FD bit stuffing worst case standard identifier arbitration phase

Tags: can

This question arises from [another one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/284797/can-fd-bit-stuffing) where the bit stuffing in data phase was under discussion.

I replicate the computation performed in [this document](https://www.can-cia.org/fileadmin/resources/documents/proceedings/2013_hickman.pdf), but according to my computation the stuff bits in the CRC field are not considered.

In figure 5 the author states that "In addition the stuff bit method for the CRC
sequence is changed. For CAN FD, stuff bits will be inserted at fixed positions, even if the preceding bits do not satisfy the bit stuffing criteria".

Hence the CRC field in the payload phase should be longer: 17+5 bits = 22 and 21+6 = 27 bits.

In the computation looks like the 5/6 stuff bits are not added to the computation, I'd expect the payload bit length for standard/no stuff bits with 64 bytes of DATA to be 549 bits long and with 8 bytes of DATA to be 96 bits long.

Any hint on this?

Comment: Hi Catosh. What 'computation' are you trying to replicate from the document? The document is just an overview of CAN-FD and contains many things.

Comment: Hi John, 
In table 6 the Author computes the Max and Min CAN frame lengths in various scenarios, and that's where the computation differs.

Answer (score 0):

Stuffing bits are usually never outlined in the protocol specification. They are added by the sending CAN controller and removed by the receiving one. Though naturally they are accounted for by the CRC calculation, which likely takes place in hardware.

The stuffing bits in the CRC itself are just there for synchronization purposes and can (by definition) not be part of the actual calculation. You can regard CRC as payload, but the CRC calculation is lower level.

As for calculating the longest possible frame length with bit stuffing in regard, that's not trivial. You have the issue where the previous stuff bit must be considered, but then also the phenomenon regarding how many padding bits before the checksum that result in a calculated checksum which in itself must be stuffed. If you truly must calculate this exactly, then I think writing a protocol simulator software that "brute force" all possible combinations and calculate stuffing + CRC would be the easiest way.

Generally when calculating frame lengths, just use some template value for the amount of stuffing, near the worst-case scenario, as I did here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/423413/6102. When doing real-time calculations you generally assume worse conditions than what's practically possible. But now of course if CAN FD has fixed bit stuffing, then you have more deterministic lengths.

Comment: Hi Lundin, you are correct: my purpose is to calculate the effective bus load, not the data rate. Luckily, we rely on fixed length can-fd payloads and frame ID, so my worst case computation is somehow "fixed" to two or three kind of frames. Usually I perform the estimation only based on payload data length since the arbitration is negligible at our data rate. I wonder if it safe to assume an overhead in the bus load of roughly 20% to account for the worst case scenarios. Eventually I can perform empiric evaluation using the oscilloscope AND the can-fd decoder.

Comment: "Though naturally they are accounted for by the CRC calculation, which likely takes place in hardware."   well ... here is the thing, they messed up and as a result the hamming distance collapses to something like HD=2 as oppose to HD=6. Koopman proved this

Comment: @Catosh It sounds sensible enough, depending on what bus load you are designing for and how deterministic the system is.

Comment: @JonRB For which one of the CRCs? There are several different ones now. (I haven't actually used CAN FD in practice yet.)

Comment: https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/pubs/01oct2013_koopman_faa_final_presentation.pdf#page=48

Comment: @Lundin Assuming the same data rate for arbitration and data phases and 64 bytes payload, it's 29bits for arbitration vs ~677 (or 543) bits for data phase, that's roughly 4%. With 8 or 4 bytes payload is closer to 50%, but those frames are sporadic and way shorter to 64bytes payload frames - we account for them during computation, but they don't overload the bus so much.

Comment: @JonRB Interesting reading, though it appears to only address classic CAN CRC-15. CAN FD uses other checksums.

Comment: iirc it still affect CAN-FD, flexray resolved this oversight. ARINC-825 covers CAN and CAN-FD and 825 stipulates needing a MIC for safety critical frames to mitigate this issue